# how to create pdf out of custom object and send it in email?

Tags: email, pdf

I want to send a pdf through email to users and the pdf is to be created from data of a custom object. How to accomplish this

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Honestly this question should not have been answered since it does not show any attempt to solve the problem for yourself. See [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for an explanation of what is expected to appear in a question on this site. Please make sure you show effort to research or resolve your question next time you post a question here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy, you can design a VF Page, maybe with a Custom Controller, or just a Standard Controller, if you don't need any calculations. Once done, you can set renderas in the apex:page parameter as follow:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
```

Once done, then you can get this PDF as a blob in Apex Class, and add the attachment in the Email.

```
    PageReference pdf =  Page.emailAttachmentEx1;
    pdf.getParameters().put('id',contactID);
    Blob b = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setContentType('application/pdf');
    efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
    efa.setInline(false);
    efa.setBody(b);
    
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {contact.Email};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setSubject('New contact is created');        
    mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
    Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
```

You can find the sources & references here:

1. https://salesforcescool.blogspot.com/2019/01/send-pdf-as-attachment-in-visualforce.html
2. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_renderas.htm

Comment: Obviously this approach requires having or gaining VF development experience. Note that, depending just what calculations are required, it could be possible to use formula or roll up fields with a standard controller.

Comment: Thanks @Somya - On a click of button on object can outlook be opened to send an email with PDF already attached?